# jenkins, git, assembla : Could not clone & permission denied

Tags: git, jenkins, assembla

1. In Jenkins, using source code management, git plugin cannot clone the remote repo.
                   Input: git.cmd and git@git.assembla.com:myfork
2. In Jenkins, not using source code management,  in Execute Windows Batch command, “gitex pull –fetch --quiet” failed to start git Extensions properly(“Unhandled exception occurred in GitExtensions.exe[3784]”).
3. For git, in Window prompt or Gitbash run from the Start menu, “git fetch/pull” failed, permission denied. 
               Environment: HOME path is correct(c:/users/username). keys are in the folder( %HOME%/.ssh and c:/git/.ssh); public keys are added to the assembla user account. Pageant is running with .ppk key added.
   **If start git bash from GitExtensions,  git pull/fetch works fine.**

Comment: Do you have any errors in your Settings page in GitExtension?  It is very picky

Answer (score 0):

1 and 3 seem to be because Jenkins server can not authenticate via ssh to assembla. Make sure the server using jenkins uses a ssh key which can access your repository - either create a bot user in assembla and add him as member to space and upload ssh key from server to his profile or upload your private/public ssh key to jenkins server.